# The ForEach Replace on this small code doesn't do what I expected it to do. What am I doing wrong here?

Tags: c#, replace, linqpad

I don't know if this is LINQPad-related or I'm doing something wrong, but this code doesn't do what I want it to do, specifically the `ForEach(...)`

My goal is to replace the "  " with an empty string; is there a better way to do this?

```
var lastNames = "SMITH, JOHNSON, WILLIAMS, JONES, BROWN";

var listLastNames = lastNames.Split(',');
var list = listLastNames.ToList(); //so I can use .ForEach
list.ForEach(i=>i.Replace(" ",String.Empty));

list.Dump(); //show it on output
```

Comment: In addition to the fact that you are discarding the result, I note that you probably want `Trim`, not `Replace`.

Comment: `list.ForEach(i=>i.Trim());` didn't work here, so I thought `Replace` might... but it didn't work as well...

Comment: `Trim()` would suffice, except you'll have the same issue because you're not retrieving the results

Answer (score 13, accepted):

As others have pointed out, strings are *immutable*. Calling Replace simply returns a new string; it does not mutate the existing string in place. Here are three ways to do what you want:

Do the transformation on *the sequence*, and convert it to a list at the end:

```
string s = "SMITH, JOHNSON, WILLIAMS, JONES, BROWN";  
List<string> lastNames = s.Split(',').Select(x=>x.Trim()).ToList();
```

Or, the same thing in query syntax:

```
string s = "SMITH, JOHNSON, WILLIAMS, JONES, BROWN"; 
var query = from lastName in s.Split(',')
            select lastName.Trim();
List<string> lastNames = query.ToList();
```

Or, make an array and mutate the array in place:

```
string s = "SMITH, JOHNSON, WILLIAMS, JONES, BROWN";  
string[] lastNames = s.Split(',');
for (int i = 0; i < lastNames.Length; ++i)
    lastNames[i] = lastNames[i].Trim();
```

Comment: Aren't the elements in the string array Immutable (as they are internally strings) ?  Meaning , is lastNames[i] immutable ?

Comment: @Dhananjay: A string is immutable. An array is a collection of variables, which are by definition mutable; that's why they're called variables.

Comment: A compiler warning when somebody ignores the return value of a `[Pure]` function would be nice. Such a warning wouldn't have many false positives, and the annotations were already created by the code-contracts team. Coding it is pretty easy too(I managed it in an afternoon while learning roslyn), and since this mistake is quite common, the gain is there too.

Comment: @CodeInChaos ReSharper recently added such a warning, which uncovered a couple of bugs in one of the applications I maintain.  We never caught the bugs before because the buggy code handles conditions that have not yet arisen in the data we process.

Answer (score 10):

`Replace` returns a new value, but doesn't affect the original String that you call it on.  To do what you need, you'd have to build a new collection with the results from `Replace` - you can do this easily with `Select`:

```
var replaced = list.Select(i=>i.Replace(" ",String.Empty));
```

Another benefit, you won't need to cast to a `List<T>` to do this.

And as others have pointed out, you can use `Trim()` as a cleaner solution than `Replace()`:

```
var collection = lastNames.Split(',').Select(i => i.Trim());
```